# Eclipse debugger is dropping out for seemingly no reason anyone dealt with this before?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have been debugging a Roman Calculator program I wrote for a class. For reasons unknown when I run the debugger after I enter in my operands the debugger seems to enter an infinite loop the "Resume" , "Suspend", "Terminate" and all the "Step" buttons on the debugger toolbar turn light grey and cannot be used. The strange thing about this is that when I run the program outside the debugger it runs completely, albeit with a few errors but no infinite loops.  what is going on?

```
        int getOperand(int which) {
        System.out.println("Enter operand " + which);
        boolean invalid_operand;
        int numeralValue;
        do {
            invalid_operand = false; //Debugger seems to drop out here

            String operand = keyboard.nextLine();
            operand.toUpperCase();
            if (operand.length() == 0)
                invalid_operand = true;
            numeralValue = convert_from_Roman(operand);

        } while (invalid_operand);
         return numeralValue;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the smallest section of code that when debugged exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: Certainly, its also worth noting that I have made it entirely through the program with the debugger once and then without me changing the code whatsoever it began having this error.

Answer (score 0):

The "Debug" view displays the running processes and threads. This view is normally the top-left window of the debug perspective. It also contains the resume, suspend, etc. buttons which you refer to.

In that view, you have to select a process or thread to control. If you haven't selected a running process or thread, then the suspend etc. controls will be grayed out. Make sure you have selected the process or thread that you want to suspend or resume.